# Color differences in the output of HTML table property "bordercolor" and CSS style "border-color" for color code "#CACACA"

Tags: html, css, colors

It might be simple, but I am surely missing something here, why the output color of both the table borders are not same?

You may either view at:
http://jsfiddle.net/samsbery/vwjGE/2/

or Run the below code:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #CACACA;
}

<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td>I am using CSS to set the bordercolor</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<table border="1" bordercolor="#CACACA">
<tr>
    <td>I am using table properties to show the bordercolor</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I dont see any color difference. Even with color picker tool they are outputting the same thing.

Comment: i am not really sure ,that there is such property like "bordercolor" but i am pretty sure there is a  "border-color"

Answer (score 0):

The border colors are the same, but the visual appearances may differ, since – depending on browser – the HTML attribute `bordercolor` may also set border style to solid, and the default is inset. To set a solid border of desired color using CSS, you need to add

```
border-style: solid
```